# Transition segue like facebook open image to fullscreen xcode

Tags: xcode, facebook, transition, segue

Can anyone say how to implement transition segue like in facebook app when i open image to fullscreen?

I fount this example http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/01/15/custom-view-controller-transitions-using-uistoryboardsegues/

but it blinking during the transition on ios7 and i don't understand how to fix it( Have anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The blinking is being caused by the temporary image that is created to simulate the transition being removed before the image is unhidden in the new view. I changed the completion block to delay by .25 seconds to allow for the image to be unhidden.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    imageView.frame = dest;

    if (self.unwinding) {
        [self.destinationViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self.sourceViewController presentViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
} completion:^(BOOL completed) {
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 1;

    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC/4);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        imageView.hidden = YES;
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    });
}];
```